# How to show Data in table?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C# and using MS Visual Studio 2010. Ans my problem is I am inserting data through textbox in a table named as (tbl_employees) and saving it successfully.

After saving when I see the table the new inserted data is not showing in tbl_employee even after updating.

Here is my code for updating table

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
     string sql = "SELECT * From tbl_employees";
     da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql , conString);
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
     cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da);
     DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc];
     dRow[1] = textBox1.Text;
     dRow[2] = textBox2.Text;
     MaxRows = MaxRows + 1; //to enable last row is still last row
     inc = MaxRows - 1;

     MessageBox.Show("Now Table is updated too. . . ");
}
```

Comment: You never execute the `SqlCommand`.  You build it, but never run it.

Comment: I can see, Select query inside the update event...

Answer (score 1):

Code with ease to understand and implement

### Insert

```
private void Insert()
{
   using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnString) )
   {
     string qry = "Insert into YourTable Select (@Val1,@Val2,@Val3)";
     using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qry,conn))
     {
       conn.Open();
       command.CommandType= CommandType.Text;
       command.Parameters.Add("@Val1",txt1.Text);
       command.Parameters.Add("@Val2",txt2.Text);
       command.Parameters.Add("@Val3",txt3.Text);
       int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
     }


   }
}
```

### Update

```
 private void Update()
    {
       using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnString) )
       {
         string qry = "Update YourTable Set Field1=@Val1,Field2=@Val2,Field3=@Val3 Where YourPrimaryKey=@Key";
         using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qry,conn))
         {
           conn.Open();
           command.CommandType= CommandType.Text;
           command.Parameters.Add("@Val1",txt1.Text);
           command.Parameters.Add("@Val2",txt2.Text);
           command.Parameters.Add("@Val3",txt3.Text);
           command.Parameters.Add("@Key",txt4.Text);
           int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();
         }


       }
    }
```

### Select

```
 private DataTable Get()
    {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnString) )
       {
         string qry = "Select * From YourTable";
         using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qry,conn))
         {
           conn.Open();
           command.CommandType= CommandType.Text;
          using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehaviour.CloseConnection))
         {
            dt.Load(reader);
         }

           con.Close();
         }


       }
      return dt;
    }
```

So now you have a Get method that returns DataTable , now you need a grid to display that data. Quite simple.

### ASP.Net

```
private void BindGrid()
{
   gridview1.DataSource = Get();
   gridView1.DataBind();
}
```

### Winforms

Same as above except we need not call `DataBind()`.